# Disappointing performance with Parallel.For

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

I am trying to speed up my calculation times by using `Parallel.For`. I have an Intel Core i7 Q840 CPU with 8 cores, but I only manage to get a performance ratio of 4 compared to a sequential `for` loop. Is this as good as it can get with `Parallel.For`, or can the method call be fine-tuned to increase performance?

Here is my test code, sequential:

```
var loops = 200;
var perloop = 10000000;

var sum = 0.0;
for (var k = 0; k < loops; ++k)
{
    var sumk = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < perloop; ++i) sumk += (1.0 / i) * i;
    sum += sumk;
}
```

and parallel:

```
sum = 0.0;
Parallel.For(0, loops,
                k =>
                    {
                        var sumk = 0.0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < perloop; ++i) sumk += (1.0 / i) * i;
                        sum += sumk;
                    });
```

The loop that I am parallelizing involves computation with a "globally" defined variable, `sum`, but this should only amount to a tiny, tiny  fraction of the total time within the parallelized loop.

**In Release build ("optimize code" flag set) the sequential `for` loop takes 33.7 s on my computer, whereas the `Parallel.For` loop takes 8.4 s, a performance ratio of only 4.0.**

In the Task Manager, I can see that the CPU utilization is 10-11% during the sequential calculation, whereas it is only 70% during the parallel calculation. I have tried to explicitly set

```
ParallelOptions.MaxDegreesOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
```

but to no avail. It is not clear to me why not all CPU power is assigned to the *parallel* calculation?

[image: Sequential vs. parallel CPU utilization]

I have noticed that a similar question has been raised on SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734295/how-to-get-max-performance-using-parallel-for-foreach-performance-timings-incl), with an even more disappointing result. However, that question also involved inferior parallelization in a third-party library. My primary concern is parallelization of basic operations in the core libraries.

**UPDATE**

It was pointed out to me in some of the comments that the CPU I am using only has 4 physical cores, which is visible to the system as 8 cores if hyper threading is enabled. For the sake of it, I disabled hyper-threading and re-benchmarked.

With hyper-threading *disabled*, my calculations are now *faster*, both the parallel and also the (what I thought was) sequential `for` loop. CPU utilization during the `for` loop is up to approx. 45% (!!!) and 100% during the `Parallel.For` loop.

Computation time for the `for` loop 15.6 s (more than twice as fast as with hyper-threading *enabled*) and 6.2 s for `Parallel.For` (25% better than when hyper-threading is *enabled*). Performance ratio with `Parallel.For` is now only **2.5**, running on 4 real cores.

So the performance ratio is still substantially lower than expected, despite hyper-threading being disabled. On the other hand it is intriguing that CPU utilization is so high during the `for` loop? Could there be some kind of internal parallelization going on in this loop as well?

Comment: Doesn't the parallel loop require a lock on sum variable ?

Comment: @SteveB I believe you are right. No performance gains with an explicit lock, though, right? :-)

Comment: no performance gain. More probably a loss of performance, but required to avoid strange behavior

Comment: Nice to see the new windows task manager in use finally ;)

Comment: Are you sure you have 8 cores? According to [this](http://ark.intel.com/products/43125/Intel-Core-i7-840QM-Processor-(8M-Cache-1_86-GHz)), for example, i7-840QM has 4 cores visible to OS as 8 due to multithreading capability.

Comment: Interesting, @EugeneRyabtsev, I am a little bit puzzled now? But `Environment.ProcessorCount` returns 8, and the Task Manager states 8 logical processors (see above), so I suppose I have a special CPU version then? Anyway, good to point out that I am running on a laptop.

Comment: Hyper threading will fool the OS that you have 8 cores. You can turn it off in the bios.

Comment: Aha? Pardon my ignorance, but if I have hyper-threading switched _on_ (8 virtual cores), is it then reasonable to expect that the parallelization would still only be able to make use of the 4 real cores? And that would then explain why I only see a 4-fold time gain?

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. Loading the core with multiple threads might be either a good or a bad idea. For example, if you have some intensive integer thread and intensive floating point thread with small datasets, they can probably coexist just fine on a single core. But if you have two heavily FP threads or threads with large datasets that compete for CPU cache your total performance might degrade. I don't know if `Parallel.For` uses conservative approach of one thread per core or it runs more threads, but your CPU just cannot run them any faster, but in general you won't gain too much.

Comment: Added updated results to the question after disabling hyper threading.

Comment: Hyperthreading technology works well in daily work with many programs. As @Magnus said it will "fool" OS but it will increase it's speed in specific workload. Problem with small amount of core is that if you do a lot of "data" specific work - a lot of read and writes to disk, then working core have to wait for this process to be done. When you have 2 logical cores per 1 physical one there is good chance that when one task is waiting for data, core can be utlized for other work. Look at this answer http://superuser.com/questions/279629/how-much-speedup-does-a-hyper-thread-give-in-theory

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Besides HyperThreading (HT), there is also another thing called Intel Turbo Boost.

Comment: @rwong - re Turbo Boost - glad you mentioned that - Turbo Boost might explain why 4 cores won't run as fast as 1 core: the whole point of Turbo Boost is that if 1 (or few) cores are active, they can be allowed to run at a higher clock rate without burning up the chip. So an interesting test would be to compare performance with that turned off. [But don't forget to turn it back on when done testing.!]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, if you are writing academic paper it is worth turning it off. However, if you want to produce "realistic performance estimates", it is better to keep it on (i.e. "CPU out-of-the-box configurations, including HT, TurboBoost, original chassis/fans/heatsink, room temperature), because this is what customers will see. It is true that it slightly reduces the incentive for parallelization, but only by a low double digit percentage.

Comment: @rwong - I meant that OP was puzzled as to why he didn't see full 4x benefit. And others posit that the reason is non-linear scaling of partitioning due to overhead of starting more threads, etc. I was merely pointing out that to remove this puzzlement, turn it off, and observe. I agree that other than for the sake of understanding "why", there is no reason to turn it off. (You didn't *explain* the significance of your comment about Turbo-Boost, so I was elaborating the impact that might have.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using a global variable can introduce significant synchronization problems, even when you are not using locks. When you assign a value to the variable each core will have to get access to the same place in system memory, or wait for the other core to finish before accessing it.
You can avoid corruption without locks by using the lighter [Interlocked.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) method to add a value to the sum atomically, at the OS level, but you will still get delays due to contention.

The proper way to do this is to update a thread local variable to create the partial sums and add all of them to a single global sum at the end. [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299.aspx) has an overload that does just this. MSDN even has an example using sumation at [How To: Write a Parallel.For Loop that has Thread Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx)

```
        int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();
        long total = 0;

        // Use type parameter to make subtotal a long, not an int
        Parallel.For<long>(0, nums.Length, () => 0, (j, loop, subtotal) =>
        {
            subtotal += nums[j];
            return subtotal;
        },
            (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, x)
        );
```

Each thread updates its own *subtotal* value and updates the global *total* using Interlocked.Add when it finishes.

Comment: Many thanks for this valuable answer, Panagiotis! I did not know of this feature, but it is definitely something I will make use of in my production code.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. The solution does not appear to speed things up substantially in the test case I have outlined above, but it adds an invaluable level of reliability to the parallelized code.

Answer (score 6):

Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach will use a degree of parallelism that it feels is appropriate, balancing the cost to setup and tear down threads and the work it expects each thread will perform.  [.NET 4.5 made several improvements to performance (including more intelligent decisions on the number of threads to spin up) compared to previous .NET versions.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235962.aspx)

Note that, even if it were to spin up one thread per core, context switches, [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) issues, resource locks, and other issues may prevent you from achieving linear scalability (in general, not necessarily with your specific code example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eric. I recompiled the code with .NET 4.5, but for my case the timings are the same. It's good to get the parallelization issues listed. I did not expect exact linear scalability even in my highly parallelized case, but I had expected better than 4 times on an 8-core CPU. Should I expect that manual thread creation would improve performance?

Comment: I am pleased to report that in this case Gustafson's Law (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson's_law) may be of interest. It is worth understanding how parallel performance changes wrt job size.

Comment: Did not know about that one, @HighPerformanceMark, but from now on I will always refer to this law regardless :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think the computation gain is so low because your code is "too easy" to work on other task each iteration - because parallel.for just create new task in each iteration, so this will take time to service them in threads. I will it like this:

```
int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();
long total = 0;

Parallel.ForEach(
    Partitioner.Create(0, nums.Length),
    () => 0,
    (part, loopState, partSum) =>
    {
        for (int i = part.Item1; i < part.Item2; i++)
        {
            partSum += nums[i];
        }
        return partSum;
    },
    (partSum) =>
    {
        Interlocked.Add(ref total, partSum);
    }
);
```

Partitioner will create optimal part of job for each task, there will be less time for service task with threads. If you can, please benchmark this solution and tell us if it get better speed up.

Comment: Look at my comment in question for more info about hyperthreading.

Comment: Jacob, according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl , the Task Parallel Library (`Parallel.ForEach` in your example) *automatically* makes a guess at how to "chunk" the requested task - it  *does not* "create new task in each iteration". [That would be bad performance.] The  `Partitioner.Create` overload you call is presumably the one that is used internally. Can't gain any benefit unless you call an overload that takes more parameters - and have tested to determine a chunk size that is better for your specific task.

Comment: ... (Since ForEach says it requires *dynamic* partitioning, I suspect it makes a guess, then uses the actual time used by the first chunk that returns, to make a better guess on next chunking - which would be hard to beat by any static parameters you provide, except in well-defined and thoroughly tested situations.)  NOTE: I don't know if this improvement happened *after* you wrote your answer; just making sure readers are aware of the situation.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for this comment, I didn't know all this details that time :) Haven't seen the article You linked to, looks like great reference to that problem. So as always .NET has already good solutions built in but always "hand tuned" tweaks can be done if needed.

Comment: @OP please check this out i believe this is the reason...it more expensive to make tasks for each loop, what you want to do is batch the big number 10000000 into groups equal to the number of cores... so 8 cores, 8 groups, then each group is done in parrell so each core does (1 250 000). Its extremely inefficient to try do each one on its own thread, tbh im surprised it faster.

Answer (score 0):

foreach vs parallel for each an example

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 };
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        //Parallel foreach
        Parallel.ForEach(array, line =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
            {

            }

        });

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel.ForEach {0}", watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
        watch = new Stopwatch();
        //foreach
        watch.Start();
        foreach (int item in array)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10000000; z++)
            {

            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ForEach {0}", watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("####");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

[image]

My CPU

Intel® Core™ i7-620M Processor (4M Cache, 2.66 GHz)

Comment: Your code has one more zero in the non-parallel case. (A classic example of the kind of mistake one can make, if one does not bother to defiine a constant or variable to hold a "magic" number that will be re-used! - in this case, the number of loop iterations.)